# Show that $m_{2}(f(A))=0$, where $m_{2}$ denotes the two-dimensional Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose that $A \subset R $ satisfies $m_{1}(A)=0$ where $m_{1}$ denotes the
one-dimensional Lebesgue measure. Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ satisfies $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq \sqrt{|x-y|},$ for every $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Show that $m_{2}(f(A))=0$, where $m_{2}$ denotes the two-dimensional Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

I am really not sure where to even start with this one.  It seems like rectifiable curves and the isoperimetric inequality may be helpful because I can see some formulas that look similar to this, but I am hoping not to spend a lot of time down that path which might be off the track entirely. Looking for direction first of all.

Comment: Use that two-dimensional Lebesgue measure coincides on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with Hausdorff $2$ dimensional measure and that $\mathcal{H}^{2}\left(f\left(A\right)\right)\le C\,\mathcal{H}^{1}\left(A\right)$ where $C$ is a constant that does not depend on the set $A$ (since $f$ is a $\frac{1}{2}$-Holder function). Finally, note that one dimensional Lebesgue measure coincides with one dimensional Hausdorff measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Is it possible you can provide some more detail?  Is it that I can prove f is Lipschitz that's the key?

Comment: Here's a simpler proof that avoids Hausdorff measure. Since $A$ has Lebesgue measure $0$ then we can find a cover of $A$ by countably many intervals $(a_{n},b_{n})$ such that the total measure is less than $\epsilon>0$. Now suppose we fix $x$ and choose some arbitrary $y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\left\lvert x-y\right\rvert\le r$. Then

$\left\lvert f(x)-f(y)\right\rvert\le\left\lvert x-y\right\rvert^{\frac{1}{2}}\le r^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: and so $f$ maps a interval of length $r$ about $x$ to a box of side length at most $r^{\frac{1}{2}}$. This box will have volume at most $r$. Thus, by forming a cover of $f(A)$ from the images of the intervals $(a_{n},b_{n})$ we obtain:

$m_{2}\left(f\left(A\right)\right)\le\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}m_{2}\left(f\left(\left(a_{n},b_{n}\right)\right)\right)\le\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lvert b_{n}-a_{n}\right\rvert<\epsilon$

where the final estimate came from the fact that we assumed this cover has total measure smaller than $\epsilon$.

Comment: @user71352: I never understand those who provide almost complete answers as comments. Why not post this as a true answer?